# ImmutablePair Hashcode

Tags: java, tuples, hashcode

I need to use an [ImmutablePair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html). But it seems that its hashcode is defined as this: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html#line.208. Which means `ImmutablePair.of("a", "a")` and `ImmutablePair.of("b", "b")` will have the same hashCode `0`:

```
ImmutablePair<String, String> p1 = ImmutablePair.of("a", "a");
System.out.println("Pair 1 hashcode: " + p1.hashCode());
ImmutablePair<String, String> p2 = ImmutablePair.of("b", "b");
System.out.println("Pair 2 hashcode: " + p2.hashCode());
```

Out put:

```
Pair 1 hashcode: 0
Pair 2 hashcode: 0
```

This seems very strange to me. Can someone explain what is the rational of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean this line *The hash code follows the definition in {@code Map.Entry}*  ?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: What's the supposed problem with 2 different entries returning the same hash code?

Comment: @fps For instance, I'm using the EqualsVerifier for Lombok verification and it will complain that two objects are not equal but their hashcodes are the same.

Comment: @Psidom That warning/complaint is plain wrong. According to Java's [`Object.hashCode` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), `It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.`

Comment: @fps Got it. Yeah, I think this makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the comment on the method definition, this implementation is required by the contract of `Map.Entry`, which `ImmutablePair` implements.

Comment: Can you expand on *this implementation is required by the contract of Map.Entry* ? I'm not quite sure I understand what it means.

Comment: Any class implementing `Map.Entry` is required to implement `hashCode` as the interface specifies.  This is...pretty much how interfaces work in Java in general: they specify required behavior.

Comment: Ok, I saw `Map.Entry` has a similar implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html. Do you have any reference why it has to implement in this way to guarantee `e1.equals(e2) => e1.hashCode() == e2.hasCode()` ?

Comment: `Map.Entry` didn't have to choose that implementation, but it did, and anything that implements it has to do it the same way.

Comment: It's also a little bit unusual to have the same key and value.  If this is *always* true, use a set; otherwise, this XOR coincidence is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I think I'm confused by my testing error. But i guess this makes sense. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Psidom Because if you cast it to Map.Entry, it needs to act exactly the same as all Map.Entry, including having matching hashcodes.  Perhaps it's artificial that it implements this interface, but it does, so it has to follow the requirements.